# ga() extremely slow when called from within a function(?)

Tags: genetic-algorithm, matlab

So I'm trying to use ga() to do some optimization. I set up the problem using optimtool and exported the settings. These are then passed to a function. Inside that function I then call ga().

Using identical data and identical settings, when I call ga() from inside the function it's 10-20 times slower than when I call it either from inside optimtool or simply using the command line on the workspace.

I'm not sure if it's the genetic algorithm itself that is slower, or if it is the fitness function.

The CPU is stuck at 100% and there's plenty of free memory, in both cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed by setting UseParallel to 'never'. No clue why that would slow it down depending on where ga() is called though.

Comment: @JohnSmith yeah those UseParallel settings are a pain. I'd suggest you answer your own question and mark as answer so it goes away from the unanswered list! :)